# Grabbing the textbox label

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello im making my first project with about 10 different textboxes where the user puts data in. when he/she clicks the the textbox the textbox text clears and a virtual numpad form pops up and when he leaves the textbox the numpad "hides".

right now (or i would) i have 2 events for every textbox, a click event and a leave event,

```
private void sheetWidthBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            vnumPadForm.Location = PointToScreen(new Point(sheetWidthBox.Right, sheetWidthBox.Top));
            vnumPadForm.Show();
        }
```

Im sure there is a way of dynamically coding that in one event and just grabbing the label name. i have played around with it a bit on my numpad like this and it works good;

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            string num = b.Text;
            SendKeys.SendWait(num);

        }
```

Like that but instead i want to get the label name

right now (or i would) i have 2 events for every textbox, a click event and a leave event,

it works but very inefficient.

Comment: a) what do you mean by label and what by name? Rather confusing! b) two events to show an input helper and to grab the data seems just right and inefficient at all. c) you can use the same 2 events for all your textboxes using the sender param to decide which tb is meant.

Comment: "you can use the same 2 events for all your textboxes using the sender param to decide which tb is meant."  can u provide an example?

Comment: Sorry when i said label name, i meant the textbox name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of the handler to something generic like "anyBox_Enter()", and update to the code below:

```
TextBox curTextBox = null;

private void anyBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    curTextBox = sender as TextBox;
    vnumPadForm.Location = PointToScreen(new Point(curTextBox.Right, curTextBox.Top));
    vnumPadForm.Show();
}
```

Note that I added a class level variable called "curTextBox" that gets set from the generic handler! This will track whatever TextBox was entered last.

Now, one by one, select each TextBox on your Form that you want to wire up to this common handler. After selecting each one, in the Properties Pane, click on the "Lightning Bolt" Icon to switch to the events for that control if they are not already showing. Find the "Enter" entry and change the dropdown to the right so that it says "anyBox_Enter".

Then in your button click handlers you can use the "curTextBox" variable to know where to send the key:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    string num = b.Text;
    if (curTextBox != null) {
        curTextBox.Text = num; // or possibly APPEND this to the TB?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much! It worked. there should be a donate button beside your guys name than i would gladly give you guys a couple bucks! your help is needed